# PHP: Function to iterate results from another function and output

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop

Seems like this would be pretty simple, however, I'm running into an issue:

Here's the code:

```
function getValidCustomers() {
    global $db;
    $getCustomers = $db->GetAll("SELECT * from customers where CustomerActive='1' AND protected IS NULL or protected=0;");
    foreach($getCustomers as $customer) {
        echo $customer['CustomerID']."\n";
    }
}

function updateValidCustomers() {
    $customers = getValidCustomers();
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($customers); $i++) {
        echo "DEBUG: $customers[$i]\n";
    }
}

updateValidCustomers();
```

Basically, the output right now is a list of the CustomerIDs (from `updateValidCustomers()`).  I just want `updateValidCustomers()` to get the data from `getValidCustomers()` and then loop through it, so that I can run another query on it that will actually manipulate the database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`getValidCustomers` doesn't return anything, maybe you mean this:

```
function getValidCustomers() {
    global $db;
    $getCustomers = $db->GetAll("SELECT * from customers where CustomerActive='1' AND protected IS NULL or protected=0;");
    foreach($getCustomers as $customer) {
        echo $customer['CustomerID']."\n";
    }
    return $getCustomers;
}
```

Comment: **sighs** - so, so close.  You're right (along with everyone else).  I originally added `return $customer['CustomerID'];` and replaced `echo $customer['CustomerID']."\n";`, but then read that it would basically exit after that matched and that obviously did not resolve my issue.  Thanks for the tip guys!

Answer (score 2):

`getValidCustomers()` doesn't return anything - it just echoes

Add `return $getCustomers` to the end of `getValidCustomers()`

Answer (score 1):

Add `return $getCustomers;` to `getValidCustomers()` :D